# Problem with the database WPF application it cannot add anything

Tags: database, wpf-controls, database-connection

I was trying to add new row to my database table and it seams that everything is going well in the application WPF and when i close the application the database has not changed(new record was not added in the database ) I tried to use dataadapters so here is my class that i use and the code behing

```
  DD.cs
   namespace WpfApplication2
  {
   class DD
  {

    private Database1DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter _cpuAdapter = null;

    protected Database1DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter Adapter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cpuAdapter == null)
                _cpuAdapter = new Database1DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter();

            return _cpuAdapter;
        }

    }





      [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
    public bool AddCPU(string Naslov, string Avtor, string Lokacija, int Broj, string
```

Zabeleska, string Izdava)
        {

```
        Database1DataSet.Table1DataTable cpus = new Database1DataSet.Table1DataTable();
        Database1DataSet.Table1Row cpu = cpus.NewTable1Row();

        cpu.Naslov = Naslov;
        if (Naslov == null) cpu.SetNaslovNull();
        else cpu.Naslov = Naslov;
        if (Avtor == null) cpu.SetAvtorNull();
        else cpu.Avtor = Avtor;
        if (Zabeleska == null) cpu.SetZabeleskaNull();
        else cpu.Zabeleska = Zabeleska;
        if (Izdava == null) cpu.SetIzdavaNull();
        else cpu.Izdava = Izdava;
        if (Broj == null) cpu.SetBrojNull();
        else cpu.Broj = Broj;
        if (Lokacija == null) cpu.SetLokacijaNull();
        else cpu.Lokacija = Lokacija;


        cpus.AddTable1Row(cpu);
        int rowsAffected = Adapter.Update(cpus);

        // Return true if precisely one row was inserted, otherwise false
        return rowsAffected == 1;
    }

 HERE IS THE CODE BEHIND

 it's an event on button click
   string n, a, z,t,l;
        int b;
        l = txtLokacija.Text;
        t = txtBroj.Text;
        b = Convert.ToInt32(t);
        n = txtNaslov.Text;
        a = txtAvtor.Text;
        z = txtZabeleska.Text;
        t = "NONE";
        txtZabeleska.Clear();
        DD obj1=new DD();
        obj1.AddCPU(n,a,l,b,z,t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found IT....when i finished the application and published then it seemed everything ok the database was working properly..i;ve restarted the PC and the newly added record